# Где почитать про безопасность сайтов?

Tags: php, безопасность, веб-программирование, взлом, sql-injection

Приблизительно разбираюсь как обезопасить разработку сайтов, например, есть такое понятие как "SQL injection" и т.д.. Но полной картины нет... Не подскажите где почитать грамотную статью на эту тему? Какие возможные неприятности ждёт сайт с точки зрения безопасности?

Comment: юзайте ORM и избегайте прямых query к ДБ. Это ибавит Вас от проблем с SQL injection

Comment: Все проблемы только в SQL injection и всё?

Comment: В гугле можно найти все что угодно. Вопрос не соответствует тематике сайта.

Comment: где почитать @Visman Вам ответил, а все что нужно чтобы избежать проблем с `SQL injection` послушайте меня. Лично я за **Doctrine** хотя меня тут за это и побить могут)

Comment: @Visman, гугл периодически сюда отправляет, поэтому можно было бы книжек накидать по аналогии с языками, вот только тема очень объемная: здесь не только защита сайта нужна, но и самого сервера, на котором сайт находится

Comment: Почитал про Doctrine - интересный подход, хотя в моём коде что-то подобное, если что-то делаю, то вызываю вначале какую-то функцию, а уже она выполняет SQL-запрос...

Comment: Как я понимаю, нужно решить проблему SQL-injection, а остальные проблемы решать по мере поступления?

Comment: https://www.owasp.org - там и книги есть...

Comment: Вот [статья про дыры чисто в FE-части](http://habrahabr.ru/company/dsec/blog/259389/). Весьма хорошо написана. Да и вообще, на хабре много чего на эту тему есть.